# How to see events in Remix

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain

I deployed a sol file in the remix,where can i find the event？
please help me...

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.8.0;   
contract con1{
uint public x;
event e1 (uint);
function f()public{
    x=5;
    emit e1(x);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you have executed a function, the bottom panel will show the transaction.

[image: transaction execution]

You can expand the details pressing on the arrow on the right. It will display details of the transaction

[image: transaction details]

The events generated should appear inside the *logs* section.

```
[
    {
        "from": "0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138",
        "topic": "0x3680e78b6fdf571695c81f108d81181ea63f50c100e6375e765b14bd7ac0adbb",
        "event": "e1",
        "args": {
            "0": "5"
        }
    }
]
```